# HTC One S notification vibrate

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, vibration, push-notifications, htc-one-s

I have a HTC One S and recently did a system update and am now running 4.1.1 (whatever that is called)

I have a few games that have push notifications e.g. bakery story, restaurant story. As soon as I updated these, the notifications play the sound I had set, but now annoyingly they also vibrate. I have been into the settings for each app and there is no option for vibrate.

I have searched through all the settings in my phone and can't find an option for notifications vibrating anywhere. I don't know how or why it turned on, but I want it off. The only option I have at the moment is to have my phone on silent all the time, or to turn the push notifications off.

Which means that I will lose out in the games. I know it's not very important but I have spent a lot of time on these games and it would be a shame to get rid of them.

Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your phone's `settings`. Go to `Sound`. Tick off the `Vibrate` (Vibration feedback for calls and notifications) option.

Comment: I only have an option for vibration feedback for calls, not notifications and yes it's off. But it's still vibrating with every push notification.

Comment: Now my phone has started to vibrate when certain contacts phone me. The vibration feedback for calls is definitely off.

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot of your Sound Settings window

Comment: I have the same problem with my One X. Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9aqnv4uhfiy8zf4/2013-02-15_23-37-26.png

Comment: Did you check the `Notification Sound` settings. I would like to see a screen shot of it as well...

Comment: @Murshid: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eygd0r8yg948r1e/2013-02-16_11-21-35.png

If somebody could be so kind to convert this to a comment. [post from @MarkM]

Comment: My menu looks exactly like Mark M's. There is no option of vibrate for notifications. It's driving me mad.

Comment: Thanks, so far I have gone through a few forums and most of them are mentioning that vibration in HTC one S is controlled by per apps. Which means turning off a particular app's notification vibration lies within its settings. But since you couldn't find it I looked out for some other solution. Found this app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygnus.vibrationwidget&hl=en Try it and let me know whether worked or not. Cheers till that.

Comment: Also I would like to know if there is a setting called `feedback` in your `sound` settings. If there is please post a screenshot of it as well. I am sorry for asking you these things. Since I don't have an HTC with me I have to go through like this.

Comment: Hi. I tried that app and it still vibrated with the notification. There is not a feedback option in my sound settings unfortunately.